# Getting to request result double into the controller

Tags: symfony

I have the follow problem i send this form to the twig but to obtain the request from the view in the controller i must put two "get", how can fix and do better the code in the controller.

//I have this builder RolType.php:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
     $builder
        ->add('nombreRol','entity',
            array('class' => 'gdrgdrBundle:Rol',
                'choice_label' => 'nombreRol',
                'required' => false,
            )) ;
}
```

//My controller mainController.php

```
$rol = new Rol();
$formRol = $this->createForm(new RolType(), $rol);
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
    $formRol->handleRequest($request);
    if ($formRol->isSubmitted() && $formRol->isValid()) {
        $rolResult = $rol->getNombreRol()->getNombreRol()));
    }
}
```

//View Rol.html.twig

```
<form action="{{ path("rol")}}" method="post" role="form">
{{ form_errors(nuevoRolForm) }}                            
{{ form_widget(nuevoRolForm._token) }}
{{ form_rest(nuevoRolForm) }}
</form>
```

//Entity Rol.php

```
class Rol
{
private $id;
private $nombreRol;
/**
 * Set nombreRol
 *
 * @param string $nombreRol
 * @return Rol
 */
public function setNombreRol($nombreRol)
{
    $this->nombreRol = $nombreRol;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get nombreRol
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getNombreRol()
{
    return $this->nombreRol;
}
}
```

Comment: Please fix the format of your code and clarify your question

Comment: Can you show the code for getNombreRol()?

Comment: //Class Rol in the entity
    /**
    * Get nombreRol
    *
    * @return string 
    */
    public function getNombreRol()
    {
    return $this->nombreRol;
    }

Comment: What are you trying to do? Get the rol that is returned by the form?